# Heapsort using multiple heaps

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I found a variant of `Heapsort` using multiple heaps at http://students.ceid.upatras.gr/~lebenteas/Heapsort-using-Multiple-Heaps-final.pdf. The solution proposes that instead of the traditional `Heapsort` algorithm, where after each swap, we do another `siftdown` to bring the highest value in the current heap to the root, we can do some other things. However, what exactly do they mean by 'other things', I cannot understand.

For example, at one point they say **We “forget”, for the time being, the existence of the root.** That surely means we are currently stalling the swapping of the highest element with the last element of the heap. However, just after some lines, they say **So far, two elements have been transferred in the sorted part of the heap.**, which runs counter to the proposition that the swapping hasn't been done yet. Also in the figure in page 97, the node with value 1 is missing, I don't know how.

Can anybody give me an idea of what exactly is the authors trying to convey, and how worthwhile can it be?

Answer (score 1):

(The line you asked about is in section 2.3, so I will explain the variation of heapsort which is proposed in section 2.3:)

When the author says **we "forget" the existence of the root**, this does *not* mean that they are stalling the swapping of the highest element. The swap is done, but they temporarily delay rebuilding the heap. After swapping the highest element into the root position, they compare the roots of the 2 subheaps, and swap one or the other with the next-highest element. *Then*, after doing *2* swaps (rather than 1), they rebuild the heap.

Then they take this idea a step further in sections 3 and 4, and propose *another* variant of heapsort, which uses more than one heap.

How do you keep more than one heap in an array? (To make it concrete, let's talk about 2 heaps.) Well, how do you keep a single heap? The root goes at index 0, its children are at 1 and 2, then the children of the left subheap are at 3 and 4, etc., right?

To put 2 heaps together in an array, keep the 2 roots at 0 and 1. The children of the first root go at 2 and 3, then the children of the 2nd root at 4 and 5... with such an arrangement, it is still possible to navigate up and down the tree by doing simple arithmetic operations on indexes.

The standard heapsort repeats 2 steps: swap the root with the last element in the "heap" area, then `siftDown` to rebuild the heap. *This* heapsort repeats the following 3 steps: compare the 2 roots to see which one is bigger, swap that one with the last element in the "heap" area, then call `siftDown` on the appropriate heap.

This requires an extra compare at each step, but the `siftDown` operations work on slightly shallower heaps, which saves more than a single compare.

Comment: I kind of understood the logic. After swapping, I know that either the left or the right node of the current root (which, as being swapped, may be smaller than either) is the next element in the line (since one of the 2 nodes has to be the 2nd highest, although the 3rd highest may be deep down). So instead of dong another `siftdown` to scoop one of those two nodes to the top, I can just compare them among themselves, swap the higher one with the current last element of the heap. That is, per `siftdown`, I am swapping 2 elements, right? So no. of `siftdown`s get reduced approximately by half?

Comment: *YES*. That's exactly right. (If this answers your question, an accept would be appreciated.)

Comment: But that hardly reduces the complexity, it still remains `O(nlog n)`. And the paper says much more, like differentiating an expression to get the optimum number of heaps, etc. This solution is rather simplistic, I don't think it is the correct interpretation of the paper.

Comment: Nothing in the paper said that this would reduce the complexity of heapsort. That's impossible, since O(n log n) is optimal for comparison-based sorts. What it does (supposedly) is reduce the number of comparisons/swaps used. That does *not* mean reducing the complexity -- it does mean reducing the constant factor which is ignored by "big-O" notation.

Comment: The line you asked about was in section 2.3, so I explained the algorithm which was proposed in that section. In sections 3 and 4, they take the idea further and propose another algorithm. I added an explanation of that one too.

Comment: What benefit will the additional heaps give? We already have some advantage by comparing the two children of the current root and swapping the higher one with the last element. What else can be achieved by the multiple heaps?

Comment: For every 2 steps, the heapsort from section 2.3 does one `siftDown` on a heap of depth `d`, and one on a heap of depth `d - 1`. The heapsort from sections 3 and 4 *only* does `siftDown` on heaps of depth `d - 1`. So it should save more compare/swap operations.

Comment: Can you just give one running example of one such operation? Don't need the pseudocode, just an example would be great in clarifying it.

Comment: Please read the last few paragraphs of my answer carefully. That should be enough that you can work through an example yourself on paper.